# Check a dict from post for multiple simultaneous conditions stored on the database

Tags: c#, razor

First of all, I'm not asking for code or for anyone doing my job for me. Just need some ideas on how these kind of rules can be applied.

I have a simple view that posts some data to the controller by unique pair (key - value). The controller receives that data into a Dictionary demoData.

In my database I have a simple table (Products) with an id and a name.

In my database I also have a table (Rules) that contains data_key, a data_value and a product_ID. The idea with this table is that when the controller receives the data values, it checks against this table and IF data_key is equal to the data_value stored, it adds the product_ID to a new dict. Something like this:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> testC([FromBody]Dictionary<string,string> demoData)
    {
        var getRules = AsDynamic(App.Data["Rules"]);
        // contains Link_datakey, Link_datavalue, Link_product

        var getProducts = AsDynamic(App.Data["Products"]);
        // contains Product_id, Product_name

        Dictionary<int, string> testdict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        var product = 0;

        foreach(var r in getRules){
            if (demoData.ContainsKey(r.Link_datakey)) {
                if (demoData[r.Link_datakey] == r.Link_datavalue) {
                    product = Convert.ToInt32(r.Link_product);
                    if (!testdict.ContainsKey(product)) {
                        testdict.Add(product, getProducts.Where(i => i.id_source == r.Link_product).First().Product_name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return testdict;
    }
```

This works fine but there are two severe limitations:

1. Rule must be of "equal" type. If I wanted something like > or < I would need to create a different if clause for each of the options, since the operator can not be variable (I assume)
2. This was created assuming only one rule would be checked for any each loop. I now need multiple rules checked like:

   if(some_datakey < some_datavalue AND someother_datakey == someother_datavalue) {
       // add the product key to the dict
   }

And the number of rules must be variable... Sometimes it's only one, but in other products it may require 2 or 3.

Can I ask for some opinions on how to implement this?
The first thing would be the rules table structure. It would no longer be enough a simple key - value - product. Probably something like rule_group_id - key - value so that the rules can be grouped, and then a new table with rule_group_id and the product to be added if all conditions return true.
Then the loops would need to accommodate the multiple rules check, and here I have no idea on how to proceed.
Any ideas you can share?

Comment: A small tip - your usages of `ContainsKey` may be replaceable with `TryGetValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an half-baked solution I came up with.

Not very happy with it.

Needs a lot of syntax review (like the TryGetValue suggested).

```
public Dictionary<int, string> testC([FromBody]Dictionary<string,string> demoData)
    {
        var getRules = AsDynamic(App.Data["Rules"]);
        // Link_group Link_datakey  Link_datavalue Link_operator

        var getRuleGroups = AsDynamic(App.Data["RuleGroups"]);
        // Link_group Link_product Link_type

        var getProducts = AsDynamic(App.Data["Products"]);
        // Product_id Product_name


        Dictionary<int, string> testdict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        var product = 0;

        var rulegetcount = 0;
        var rulesetcount = 0;

        int tryparsedataint;
        bool tryparsedatabool;
        int tryparsevalueint;
        bool tryparsevaluebool;

        foreach(var rg in getRuleGroups.Where(t => t.Link_type == "add")){
            rulegetcount = getRules.Where(r => r.Link_group == rg.Link_group).Count();
            rulesetcount = 0;
            foreach(var r in getRules.Where(r => r.Link_group == rg.Link_group)){
                if (demoData.ContainsKey(r.Link_datakey)) {
                    if(r.Link_operator == "==") {
                        if (demoData[r.Link_datakey] == r.Link_datavalue) {
                            rulesetcount ++;
                        }
                    } else if(r.Link_operator == "<") {
                        tryparsedatabool = Int32.TryParse(demoData[r.Link_datakey], out tryparsedataint);
                        tryparsevaluebool = Int32.TryParse(r.Link_datavalue, out tryparsevalueint);
                        if(tryparsedatabool && tryparsevaluebool) {
                            if (tryparsedataint < tryparsevalueint) {
                                rulesetcount ++;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(r.Link_operator == ">") {
                        tryparsedatabool = Int32.TryParse(demoData[r.Link_datakey], out tryparsedataint);
                        tryparsevaluebool = Int32.TryParse(r.Link_datavalue, out tryparsevalueint);
                        if(tryparsedatabool && tryparsevaluebool) {
                            if (tryparsedataint > tryparsevalueint) {
                                rulesetcount ++;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(r.Link_operator == "!=") {
                        if (demoData[r.Link_datakey] != r.Link_datavalue) {
                            rulesetcount ++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (rulegetcount == rulesetcount) {
                product = Convert.ToInt32(rg.Link_product);
                if (!testdict.ContainsKey(product)) {
                    testdict.Add(product, getPropList.Where(i => i.Product_id == rg.Link_product).First().Product_name);
                }
            }
        }

        return testdict;
    }
```